# I am trying to fill tables with values but I got conversion failed error

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am creating a database and I am trying to fill table with values but I got error

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Code of the query:

```
INSERT INTO Register_of_crimes (id_crime , Date, List_of_crime , Fine)
VALUES ('1', '1989-3-6', 'Rušenie nočného kľudu', '30'),
       ('2', '1991-3-3', 'Poškodzovanie cudzej veci', '50'),
       ('3', '2011-3-3', 'Pitie alkoholu na verejnosti', '20'),
       ('4', '1999-6-5', 'Výtržnosti na verejnosti', '40')
```

Table I created :

```
CREATE TABLE Register_of_crimes
(
    id_crime int,
    Date date,
    List_of_crime varchar (150),
    Fine money,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_crime)
)
```

Thank you for all your answers and advice

Comment: Which database product are you using? Judging by the error message I'd expect it doesn't like your date format, and you should use a standard format such as an ISO8601 compatible one, e.g. `YYYY-MM-DD`. Therefore I'd expect that `1991-3-3` would need to be changed to `1991-03-03`, for example.

Comment: Also try national character literals for non-ASCII characters. E.g. `N'Rušenie nočného kľudu'`.

Comment: And no need to pass numeric values as character strings, i.e. pass 2 as 2, not '2'.

Comment: Which database are you using? The date format standards depends based on the database you use.

Comment: @ADyson I changed it to `1991-03-03` format but It didn't help what should I try?

Comment: @JimMacaulay Microsoft SQL server managment studio. And it's on my let's say school database

Comment: I guess, it would be nice to change List_of_crime to nvarchar(150) to handle special characters

Comment: I tried running the CREATE and then the INSERT, they both work flawlessly for me. Maybe the server or database settings are preventing it from correctly parsing the YYYY-M-D strings, that's the only thing I can think of.

Comment: FYI managment studio is just a front-end application (one of several you can use to connect to the database, if you wanted to). the actual database server product itself is simply known as Microsoft SQL Server. Make sure you understand the difference between the client-side and the server-side components of the environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should actually use `19910303`, no dashes.

SQL Server interprets `1991-03-03` as `YYYY-DD-MM` in most languages, as this demonstrates:

```
SET LANGUAGE Deutsch;    
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '1991-03-13');
```

Result:

> Msg 242, Level 16, State 3
> Bei der Konvertierung eines varchar-Datentyps in einen datetime-Datentyp liegt der Wert außerhalb des gültigen Bereichs.

(It actually works fine if you convert to `date`, but that is an exception, and it is much better practice to just always the same, unambiguous format.)

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bd45ca8fedd0403a4effedf73f5040e6)
- Plenty more about dates in [Dating Responsibly](https://sqlblog.org/dates)

You also should make sure that strings that may contain Unicode characters are declared with the right data type (and potentially the right collation), and all string literals are prefixed with `N`. And also integers to *not* be surrounded by string delimiters. So I would expect:

```
List_of_crime nvarchar(150)
--------------^
```

...and...

```
VALUES (1, '19890306', N'Rušenie nočného kľudu', 30)
```

Comment: this actualy works for me

Answer (score 1):

Use a unambiguous date and time format. In SQL Server those are `yyyyMMdd` and `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.nnnnnnn`. Also when your data types are numerical *don't* wrap them in single quotes (`'`), that is for literal strings. I *assume* your values were in the format `yyyy-M-d`:

```sql
INSERT INTO Register_of_crimes (id_crime , Date, List_of_crime , Fine)
VALUES (1,'19890306','Rušenie nočného kľudu', 30),
       (2,'19910303','Poškodzovanie cudzej veci',50),
       (3,'20110303','Pitie alkoholu na verejnosti',20),
       (4,'19990605','Výtržnosti na verejnosti',40);
```

On a separate note, you may find that the values you insert for `List_of_crime` suffer data loss, due to the characters being outside of the code page (for example `ľ` may be implicitly converted to `l`). If this is the case you'll need to `ALTER` your table so that `List_of_crime` is an `nvarchar` and then use `nvarchar` literal strings, such as `N'Rušenie nočného kľudu'`.